# Change display style in xlop multiplication

Tags: formatting, xlop

When I use [`xlop`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xlop/tex/xlop.tex) for multiplication for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}

\opmul{0.436}{0.35}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image: Output Xlop]

However I need the following style:

[image: output]

How can I achieve this?

I guess it should be possible with some modifications of the macro `\op@muldisplayone` however my plain-tex abilities are too limited to do this...

Comment: May I ask is this a standard layout in some context? I know of several multiplication layouts but I have never seen this one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This notation is the one taught in school in Germany

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with `xlop`, but with some labor with `expl3` you can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showmult}{mm}
 {
  \anna_showmult:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__anna_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__anna_factora_tl
\tl_new:N \l__anna_factorb_tl
\tl_new:N \l__anna_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l__anna_table_tl
\seq_new:N \l__anna_partial_products_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \anna_showmult:nn #1 #2
 {
  % remove leading zeros and the decimal point
  \tl_set:Nn \l__anna_factora_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__anna_factorb_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\A 0\.0*|\.) } { } \l__anna_factora_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\A 0\.0*|\.) } { } \l__anna_factorb_tl
  \tl_reverse:N \l__anna_factorb_tl
  % compute the partial products
  \tl_clear:N \l__anna_padding_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__anna_partial_products_seq
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__anna_factorb_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__anna_partial_products_seq
     { \int_to_arabic:n { ##1 * \l__anna_factora_tl } \l__anna_padding_tl }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__anna_padding_tl { \anna_padding: }
   }
  \seq_reverse:N \l__anna_partial_products_seq
  % do the multiplication
  \tl_set:Nx \l__anna_result_tl { \fp_eval:n { #1 * #2 } }
  % prepare the table
  \tl_set:Nn \l__anna_table_tl { #1\cdot#2 \\ \hline }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__anna_table_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l__anna_partial_products_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ } }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__anna_table_tl { \\ \hline \l__anna_result_tl }
  $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
  \l__anna_table_tl
  \end{array}$
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \anna_padding: { \hphantom{0} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\showmult{0.436}{0.35}

\medskip

\showmult{1.2}{34}

\medskip

\showmult{1.222}{3.4}

\medskip

\showmult{0.022}{3.04}
\end{document}
```

[image]